# Mysql subqueries with conditions, different results

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem with a project I'm working on.

I have 2 tables. First table is `workorder`. This table consists of the following columns:

- id
- relation_code
- generated
- exportready

Second table is `workorder_records`. Columns:

- id
- workorder_id
- description
- approved

I need to select every `workorder` where generated = 0 and exportready = 0 and its records count. But, only records where approved = 0 and description != ''.

I've written this query for it:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM workorder_records
WHERE workorder_records.approved = 0
AND workorder_records.workorder_id = workorder.id
AND workorder_records.description != ''
) as totalunapproved
FROM workorder
WHERE workorder.generated = 0
AND workorder.exportready = 0
```

I get the correct result when I execute this in phpMyAdmin. When I run this through a PHP script connected to the same database, I get different results. For example, a result where workorder_records.description was actually empty but still returned by the query function.

SQL Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea8aa/3

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I solved the problem by doing the checks in PHP. This is of course not ideal but I just can't figure out why the conditional subquery works in PHPMyAdmin and not in my PHP script.

Comment: This query should do what you want and the results should be stable.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea8aa/3

Comment: Why use us select? This would seem to be able to be done via standard join.

Comment: @MikeBrant Would that change the result of the query? If so, how would I go about changing this query into a JOIN query?

Comment: Please check whether data type of each column in local and live same?

Comment: @Gunaseelan They are.

Comment: For checking purpose, provide the table result which you want to receive at the end of query execution.

Comment: @RutgerSpeksnijder . . . Your SQL Fiddle is returning the correct values as far as I can tell.

Comment: Solved it by doing the checks in PHP. I don't understand why the conditional checks in the subquery work in PHPMyAdmin but not in my PHP script. But at least it works now, just not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this

```
workorder_records.description != ''
```

to

```
workorder_records.description IS NOT NULL
```

And make workorder_records.description by default as null.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't help.